# Modal rendering and onClick in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm kind of new to React and I'm having difficulty in invoking components through `onClick` event of a button.

Given below is the code segment

```
function Dev({value}){
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardImg top width="100%" src={value.src} alt="Card image cap" />
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle className='text-card'>{value.title}</CardTitle>
                <CardText className='text-text'>{value.text}</CardText>
                <Button className='text-button' onClick={(value)=>{
                    return(
                        <div>
                            {value.id ? <Login /> : <Sign />}
                        </div>
                    )
                }}>{value.button}<i class={value.icon} aria-hidden="true"></i></Button>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>
);
}
```

`value.id` is either `true` or `false`, but either way the `onClick` is not firing.

The components `Login` and `Sign` are actually components consisting of a Modal.

Some help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Returning JSX from the click function doesn't make any sense. What do you want to happen when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: To render the Login/Sign component

Comment: Set a state when the button is clicked, show the components when the state is set. Look up state and conditional rendering in the docs.

Comment: So updating the state is the only way to render the components?

Comment: State is the best way to do it, yes. Returning from `onClick` doesn't work, if it did, where would it be rendered? Would it replace the button? The Component? Get added to the existing JSX somewhere? Basically, there is no logical way for returning JSX from the `onClick` to work (thankfully it doesn't). So setting a flag in state and conditionally rendering is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you should add state for you component and keep something `isButtonClicked` in it:

```
function Dev({ value }) {
  const [isButtonClicked, setIsButtonClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setIsButtonClicked(true);

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardImg top width="100%" src={value.src} alt="Card image cap" />
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle className="text-card">{value.title}</CardTitle>
        <CardText className="text-text">{value.text}</CardText>
        <Button className="text-button" onClick={handleClick}>
          {value.button}
          <i class={value.icon} aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </Button>
        {isButtonClicked && (value.id ? <Login /> : <Sign />)}
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
}
```